# Can we generate a block skew-symmetric matrix by a operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-algebras, block-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

Suppose we have following speical block matrix
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & X_3 & -X_2\\
-X_3& 0& X_1\\
X_2 &-X_1 &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $X1,X2,X3 \in R^{n \times n}$ and not invertible.**Can we generate $X$ by a oprator $\mathcal{A}$ of $[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ or $\begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2 \\X_3\end{bmatrix}$**,so we don't need to store $X$,only need to store $X_1,X_2,X_3$ and obtain $X$ through $X_1,X_2,X_3$.

Comment: The answer is, in a sense, trivially yes. The function $\mathcal A$ satisfying 
$$
\mathcal A([X_1,X_2,X_3]) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & X_3 & -X_2\\
-X_3& 0& X_1\\
X_2 &-X_1 &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
can be called an "operator". However, it seems likely that you have something more specific in mind when you use the term "operator". Please clarify exactly what it is that you're asking for.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I want to find the operator $\mathcal{A}$,maybe $\mathcal{A}$  could be represented  as a matrix

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "$\mathcal A$ could be represented as a matrix"? Are you specifically looking to represent $\mathcal A$ as a function of the form $\mathcal A(X) = PXQ$ for matrices $P,Q$? If so, then no such matrices $P,Q$ exist.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I just to find a $\mathcal{A}$ such that $$\mathcal{A}([X_1,X_2,X_3]) = \begin{bmatrix}0 &X_3&-X_2\\-X_3 & 0 & X_1\\X_2 &-X_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$,so I can do calculate on $\mathcal{A}([X_1,X_2,X_3])$ instead of $$\begin{bmatrix}0 &X_3&-X_2\\-X_3 & 0 & X_1\\X_2 &-X_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$,but I can't find the $\mathcal{A}$.Can you help me,thanks in advance

Comment: Please answer the questions that I asked in my previous comment

Comment: @BenGrossmann "$\mathcal{A}$ could be represented as a matrix",I just hope $\mathcal{A}$ is a matrix,  if it can't be represented as a matrx,I want a explicit expression of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mathcal{A}([X_1,X_2,X_3])=X$,and don't want to find $\mathcal{A}(X)=PXQ$

Comment: I still don't understand what you're looking for, maybe this will help. What do you expect to be the difference between plugging $[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ into this "explicit expression" of $\mathcal A$ and constructing $X$ directly? What advantage do you expect from using this operator $\mathcal A$, if it exists?

Comment: @BenGrossmann If I find $\mathcal{A}$, i don't need to store $X$, 
 I only need to store $\mathcal{A}$ and $X_1,X_2,X_3$ in the calculation, so I try to find a explict expression of $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: If that's the only reason you're interested in this operator, then all you need is to write a function in your script that takes matrices $X_1,X_2,X_3$ and generates the block matrix $X$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I want to find the operator $\mathcal{A}$ to reveal the relation between $\mathcal{A}$ and $X_1,X_2,X_3$,then I can code easily.Can you give me some references in how to find this $\mathcal{A}$,thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing to "find" here. If we say that $\mathcal A$ is the function defined such that
$$
\mathcal{A}([X_1,X_2,X_3]) = \begin{bmatrix}0 &X_3&-X_2\\-X_3 & 0 & X_1\\X_2 &-X_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
$$
then we have described the operator as explicitly as we possibly can. Nothing about this operator reveals a relationship between its $X$ and its submatrices $X_i$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann So it's impossible to write an explicit expression for $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: I would say that $\mathcal A$, as I have presented it, is written explicitly. What exactly do you think is missing that would make it "explicit"?

Comment: @BenGrossmann for example if $$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\0\end{bmatrix}[x_1,x_2,x_3]=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 &x_2&x_3\\0 &0&0\\0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix}$$,if $X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 &x_2&x_3\\0 &0&0\\0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix}$,then I think $\mathcal{A}$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That seems to imply, as I suggested earlier, that you're looking for matrices $P,Q$ such that $\mathcal A(Y) = PYQ$. As I said then, no such matrices exist.